# R logical operators - When to use the exclamation point vs the dash (!x and -x)?

Tags: r, machine-learning

For example, consider the following method of splitting data...

```
set.seed(1)
train=sample(1:nrow(x),size=nrow(x)/2)
test=(-train)
y.test=y[test]
```

and

```
set.seed(1)
train=sample(1:nrow(x),size=nrow(x)/2)
test=(!train)
y.test=y[test]
```

I proceed with the ! operator trying to fit a ridge regression model on the training set, and evaluate its MSE on the test set, using λ = 4.

```
ridge.mod=glmnet(x[train,],y[train],alpha=0,lambda=grid,thresh=1e-12)
ridge.pred=predict(ridge.mod,s=4,newx=x[test,])
Warning message:
In cbind2(1, newx) :
number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

What exactly is happening when I use the !train as opposed to -train? I don't get an error when using the dash operator.

Comment: Start with reading help("[").

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `test` variables. In the first case, you're getting a bunch of negative integers, which in R, remove the specified element from a vector:

```
> (1:10)[-5]
[1]  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 10
```

In the second case, you're treating the numbers as Boolean/logical values, so they're all TRUE, and the `!` makes them all FALSE.

```
> (1:10)[c(FALSE, FALSE)]
integer(0)
```

not that useful...

Comment: You might want to change the first example to make it clear that it's the 5th element that's removed, rather than the element whose value is 5.

Comment: Can you clarify? So if I define test as -train, then my test set is a vector of every element that was removed from x? What does that mean? And if I define test as !train, then my training set is a vector of all "False"?. I understand that I am randomly selecting a subset of numbers between 1 and n which are then used as the indices for the training observations. Now I want to define test as all the other observations that are not in my training set. Why does -train work here but !train???

Comment: `train=sample(1:nrow(x),size=nrow(x)/2)` gives you a random sample of half the row indices of `x`, where `x` should be your data frame (but you later seem to use `y` as your data frame, which is confusing, so I'm going to assume your data frame is called `x`). `x[train, ]` keeps only the rows of `x` that are in `train`. `x[-train, ]` removes the rows of `x` that are in `train`, leaving a data frame with all the rows that are not in train.

Comment: Use `!` (the negation operator) when you want to use boolean logic to select rows. For example (using the built-in `mtcars` data frame): `mpg.cutoff = mtcars$mpg > 25` creates a logical vector. Then run `mtcars[mpg.cutoff, ]` and `mtcars[!mpg.cutoff, ]`. Of course, you can just do `mtcars[mtcars$mpg > 25 , ]` or `mtcars[!mtcars$mpg > 25 , ]`.